# Declaration group closing '}' not found using xhtmltopdf

Tags: html, css, django, html-to-pdf, xhtml2pdf

I am getting below error while converting html to pdf.

Declaration group closing '}' not found:: (u'{\n    0', u'% { -webkit-transfor')

Code:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); 
    }
    100% { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use an unsupported property. Here's a list of the [xhtml2pdf supported CSS properties](http://xhtml2pdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=css#supported-css-properties).

For more control and faster pdf creation I would recommend looking into ReportLab.